# add heading attribute to numbered list

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a large numbered list with many levels of indentation.

I want to maintain the numbering **and** apply a `heading` to each numbered item so that each item will appear in the `Navigation` sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

The best resource to read on how to do this is by a woman named Shauna Kelly. Shauna has since passed away but a dedicated group of people keep her website going. No gimmicks no tricks no spam just a really good learning resource.

[How to create numbered Headings or Outline Numbering](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

The article is about Word 2007 and 2010, but it still applies if you are running 2013, 2016 and even the Mac versions of Word.

If you'd rather not click the link, then do a web search on **ShaunaKelly.com** and find your way to the article from there,.